# How is a linear combination of pauli operators applied to a quantum circuit in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms

Consider a quantum circuit of 2 qubit:

`quantumcircuit = QuantumCircuit(2)`

If one wishes to apply a Pauli-X operator to the first qubit, one writes:
`quantumcircuit.x(0)`

But how should it be written programmatically if the wish is to apply a Bell measurement bases $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[X - Z]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[X - Z]$ is unitary. You can easily check that:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
import numpy as np

op = SparsePauliOp(['X', 'Z'], [1 / np.sqrt(2), -1 / np.sqrt(2)])
print(op.is_unitary())
```

So, you can add it to your circuit using [`QuantumCircuit.unitary()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.unitary) method:

```
quantumcircuit.unitary(op, [0])
```